# C++ STD Vector push_back doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, vector, sdl, libconfig

I'm making a game with SDL that used libconfig to read some settings from a file. The problem is that I made a class called `ClipList` that contains a `std::vector<SDL_Rect>` to store the settings but when trying to add `SDL_Rect` objects to the vector, for some reason push_back does nothing and I end up with an empty vector.

This is the class:

```
class ClipList
{
    public:
        ClipList();
        ClipList(int);
        virtual ~ClipList();
        void addClip(int,int,int,int);
        void getClip(int,SDL_Rect*);
        int getLength();
    protected:
    private:
    std::vector<SDL_Rect> clips;
};
ClipList::ClipList(int l)
{
    clips.reserve(l);
}

void ClipList::addClip(int x,int y,int w,int h){
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = w;
    rect.h = h;
    clips.push_back(rect);
}

void ClipList::getClip(int i,SDL_Rect* rect){
rect = &(clips.at(i));
}

int ClipList::getLength(){
    return clips.size();
}
```

And this is the function where I initialize the ClipList object. This function gets called from main.

```
void set_clips(Config* placlips,ClipList* clips, ClipList* flipclips){
    const Setting& root = placlips->getRoot();
    int x,y,w,h;
    try{
        Setting& clipsett = root["clips"];
        int cliplen = clipsett.getLength();
        clips = new ClipList(cliplen);
        flipclips = new ClipList(cliplen);
        for(int i=0;i<cliplen;i++){
            const Setting& c = clipsett[i];
            if(!(c.lookupValue("x",x)&&c.lookupValue("y",y)&&c.lookupValue("w",w)&&c.lookupValue("h",h))){
                continue;
            }
            clips->addClip(x,y,w,h);
        }
    }catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex){
        cerr << "Setting not found at" << nfex.getPath() << endl;
    }
}
```

Regardless of whether the `ClipList` objects get initialized in `main` or `set_clips`, `clips.push_back(rect)` doesn't work. The capacity of the vector changes but no object gets stored so I end up with a segfault if I try to do anything else with the vector, even checking if the vector is empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess, the signature of the function

```
void set_clips(Config* placlips,ClipList* clips, ClipList* flipclips);
```

is the culprit. You are allocating memory for `clips` and `flipclips` in this function but since the pointers are passed by value, the calling function does not see the allocated memory.

If you change the function signature to:

```
void set_clips(Config* placlips, ClipList*& clips, ClipList*& flipclips);
```

your problems should go away.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, though passing the pointers by reference got the code to compile the `SDL_Rect` objects still didn't get stored in memory. I got around the problem by initializing the ClipList objects in `main`, and passing the ClipList objects by reference instead of the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`clips.push_back(rect)` is working fine. Your `set_clips` function allocates new ClipList instances but does not pass those pointers back to the caller. The caller is probably attempting to use a garbage pointer as an initialise instance and that is why you are getting a segfault.

You need to pass the created objects back. You should use something like std::shared_ptr<> to do that instead of bare pointers.

Update on how to do this without using std::shared_ptr<>:

You need to keep track of ownership and deal with exceptions. In terms of the actual passing, the rule I use (originally from Lakos in "Large Scale C++ Software Design") is that parameters that are return values (as you are attempting to use them) are pointers, and read-only parameters are by value or const-reference. Return values come first.

So, your `set_clips` function should look like this:

```
void set_clips(ClipList** clips, ClipList** flip_clips, Config const& placlips)
```

When you call `set_clips` you pass a pointer to each pointer that will receive the allocated value, and pass a const-reference to the placlips object that is not modified by the function.

You would all it something like this:

```
ClipList* clips = 0;
ClipList* flip_clips = 0;
set_clips(&clips, &flip_flips, placlips);
// ... then do whatever comes next.
```

But combining those rules with std::shared_ptr<> or boost::shared_ptr<> is better and the "modern C++" style.

Comment: How can I do that without shared_ptr?